zref-clever across an external file
I am trying to build a reference to a theorem-like environment on another file, using zref-clever and doing, what I think is supposed to work, but running into problems defining the name of the link in the new file:
documentA.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{volume}{Volume 1}
\zref@addprop{main}{volume}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{\bf Thm}[section]
\zcRefTypeSetup{thm}{
Name-sg = Theorem ,
name-sg = theorem ,
Name-pl = Theorems ,
name-pl = theorems ,
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section A1}
    \label{sec:section-a1}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Testing the crossreference}
    \label{fig:01}
\end{figure}

\begin{thm}
        \label{thm1}
        This is a Theorem
\end{thm}

\end{document}

documentB.tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\zexternaldocument[A-]{documentA}

\newtheorem{thm}{\bf Thm}[section]
\zcRefTypeSetup{myconjecture}{
Name-sg = Theorem ,
name-sg = theorem ,
Name-pl = Theorems ,
name-pl = theorems ,
}


\begin{document}
\section{Section B1}
\label{sec:section-b1}
\zcref{A-fig:01} of \zcref{A-sec:section-a1} of \zref[volume]{A-sec:section-a1}

\zcref{A-thm1}

\end{document}

I get the proper names for the Section, Figure, etc ... but not for the defined {thm} environment.
Added on 10/20/2024: The only thing wrong with the file(s) above is the argument of \zcRefTypeSetup, once replaced with thm it works. But anyone thinking about using this should read Gustavo's  solution completely, because the two other options below are much better organized and leads to easier and more maintainable files.

That's because, in documentB.tex you are calling \zcRefTypeSetup{myconjecture} instead of \zcRefTypeSetup{thm}. But, better than that would be to just set countertype={thm=theorem} (in both documents), the theorem type is already defined by the package. Or, even easier, create the newtheorem with the theorem counter (I'm not sure this is not already taken though).

I am glad my typo is leading to a much better understanding of the solution.

The warning you get when compiling documentB.tex is:
Package zref-clever Warning: Reference format option 'name-sg' undefined for
(zref-clever)                type 'thm' on line 22.

And the problem is that, in that document, you are setting the type myconjecture instead of thm (you are calling \zcRefTypeSetup{myconjecture}).
But, you don't actually need to setup names for theorems. zref-clever already defines a theorem type (for supported languages). So, all you have to do is connect your thm with that type.
You have two alternatives. Either you tell zref-clever that the thm counter is of type theorem, which can be done with the countertype option:
\zcsetup{countertype={thm=theorem}}

Or you can define your \newtheorem to use the theorem counter, in which case you need no additional setup, since zref-clever uses the counter as the type by default. So you could, e.g.:
\newtheorem{theorem}{\bf Thm}[section]

Or, if you really need the environment to be named thm, something like:
\newcounter{theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}[theorem]{\bf Thm}

Note that, if you have multiple environments using the same counter, as is a common use case for \newtheorem, you are bound to the first approach, and the setup must be done at the right place, in the corresponding environment (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/728567/105447 for a recent case here in the site). The user manual has a How-to section, with four examples, for common \newtheorem use cases and how to handle them. (I suppose you are acquainted with it, since \zcRefTypeSetup{myconjecture} seems oddly familiar ;-).
Another observation, since you are working with (zref-)xr. The countertype option (and reftype too) affect how the labels are set, so the setting must be in place where this is happening. With either of the above approaches you can check your documentA.aux file to find your thm1 label is of type theorem. With that in place, documentB will have no trouble with the imported label. But, in general, when using (zref-)xr, you must take care things are consistent across the documents involved.
In full, per request in the comments. First solution:
documentA.tex:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{volume}{Volume 1}
\zref@addprop{main}{volume}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{\bf Thm}[section]
\zcsetup{countertype={thm=theorem}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section A1}
    \label{sec:section-a1}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Testing the crossreference}
    \label{fig:01}
\end{figure}

\begin{thm}
        \label{thm1}
        This is a Theorem
\end{thm}

\end{document}

documentB.tex:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\zexternaldocument[A-]{documentA}

\newtheorem{thm}{\bf Thm}[section]
\zcsetup{countertype={thm=theorem}}

\begin{document}
\section{Section B1}
\label{sec:section-b1}
\zcref{A-fig:01} of \zcref{A-sec:section-a1} of \zref[volume]{A-sec:section-a1}

\zcref{A-thm1}

% Also works with babel/polyglossia, as you seem to be worried about this in
% the comments.
\selectlanguage{french}
\zcref{A-thm1}

\end{document}

Second approach.
documentA.tex:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{volume}{Volume 1}
\zref@addprop{main}{volume}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{theorem}{\bf Thm}[section]
% or (but in this case adjust the environments):
% \newcounter{theorem}[section]
% \newtheorem{thm}[theorem]{\bf Thm}

\begin{document}
\section{Section A1}
    \label{sec:section-a1}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Testing the crossreference}
    \label{fig:01}
\end{figure}

\begin{theorem}
        \label{thm1}
        This is a Theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{document}

documentB.tex:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{zref-xr}
\zexternaldocument[A-]{documentA}

\newtheorem{theorem}{\bf Thm}[section]
% or (but in this case adjust the environments):
% \newcounter{theorem}[section]
% \newtheorem{thm}[theorem]{\bf Thm}

\begin{document}
\section{Section B1}
\label{sec:section-b1}
\zcref{A-fig:01} of \zcref{A-sec:section-a1} of \zref[volume]{A-sec:section-a1}

\zcref{A-thm1}

% Also works with babel/polyglossia, as you seem to be worried about this in
% the comments.
\selectlanguage{french}
\zcref{A-thm1}

\end{document}

In either case, the result is:


I did fix the misuse of the encironment name and things now process fien, but I would like to fully understand your two other -- better -- options, especially because I have several environemnts From your resumed answer I have not been able to fully understand what repleces what and how the language (which is very important to me) play a rtole here. Woukld you be ablke to include a full documentB.tex for the two solutions?

@TeXApprentice The answer already directs you to the \newtheorem how-tos in the manual. And there's also a section dedicated to reference types. This should more than suffice. If it still doesn't, you're free to ask other things, of course. But don't do so by editing this question in a way that renders the answer meaningless. If you have a new question, just ask another one (possibly linking to this one, if they are actually related).

Thanks Gustavo, this is really great. Thanks for taking the time. I have a whole new appreciation for the package now, and I am starting to understand how much more powerfull it is for references compared to the previous solutions.
